# config.yml not found on Databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I have python project which queries the SQL Server database and does some transformation within the SQL server. This project is using using config.yml which has all the DB related properties.

Now, I'am trying to host this on databricks and so that I can run it as notebook. I have all the python files imported to the databricks workspace. But while executing the main .py file I get the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.yml'
```

Because Databricks does not allow me to import a .yml file into the work space. What can I do to run this  python project so that it read the .yml file and create a DB connection properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your .yaml file to the DBFS, and point to it. You can do it [different ways](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#access-dbfs):

1. Using `dbutils.fs.put` (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#dbutils))
2. Using Databricks CLI's `databricks fs cp` command from your local machine - you will need to install on it `databricks-cli` python package, and configure to use personal access tokens if they are enabled in your workspace (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#databricks-cli))
3. Upload file via file browser, or directly from the notebook's menu (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#file-upload-interface))

Because your code works with "local" files, you will need to specify the path to the file as `/dbfs/<file-path-on-dbfs` - in this case, file will be read by "normal" Python's file API.